# QML Row not sizing to fit contents

Tags: qml, row, size, width

I have defined a couple of QML classes (MyFrame and MyGroup) which contain Rows.  I populate the MyFrame row with two MyGroup's, as well as with two rectangles.  Each MyGroup also contains two rectangles.

When run I only see the green and pink rectangles beside each other as shown below.  All of the rectangles in the MyGroup's have 0 width (I think).
[image]

If I hard code a width:130 in the MyGroup then all shows normally as shown below.
[image]

Why aren't each of the "MyGroup" objects resizing their width to hold the two rectangles therein?  How can I fix my code such that MyGroup resizes to fit its row contents?

*main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 768
    visible: true

    MyFrame {
        MyGroup {
            Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                color: "orange"
            }
            Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                color: "black"
            }
        }
        MyGroupDivider {}
        MyGroup {
            Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                color: "red"
            }
            Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                color: "blue"
            }
        }
        MyGroupDivider {}
        Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 60
            color: "green"
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 60
            color: "pink"
        }
    }

}
```

*MyFrame.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    default property alias contents: frameContents.children
    anchors {
        top: parent.top
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
    }
    height: 100
    Row {
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            margins: 5
        }
        id: frameContents
    }
}
```

*MyGroup.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    default property alias contents: groupContents.children
    anchors {
        top: parent.top
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }
    Row {
        anchors {
            fill: parent
        }
        id: groupContents
        spacing: 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your setup and use of anchors is forcing sizing from top down, except when it comes to the width of the MyGroup component. Since you aren't setting a width there, that Item is ending up with width == 0.

When you want things to size to their contents rather than the parent's dimensions you have to take an approach like this:

MyGroup.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    default property alias contents: groupContents.children
    implicitHeight: groupContents.implicitHeight
    implicitWidth: groupContents.implicitWidth

    Row {
        id: groupContents
        spacing: 5
    }
}
```

Some of the things to keep in mind about what is going on here.

1. "implicit" sizes declare the preferred desired width and height of an Item. These are usually inspected by, honored by and reflected by containers.
2. Items don't size to contain their children unless you specifically make them do so. On the other hand, containers like Row do set their implicit sizes to reflect the implicit sizes of their children.
3. When constraining from the inside (content) out via children, it's implicit sizes from the bottom up your hierarchy as far as you need them.
4. When constraining from the outside in via parents, it's anchors all the way down until you get to instances using implicit sizes. Note that anchoring overrides implicit size behavior.

Many applications need a mix of both bottom up implicit sizing and top down anchor sizing. It can be an art to get it just right in complex situations.

The standard controls tend to either have a native implicit size or are a container and the implicit size will reflect their children. If you make your own containers/widgets, you have to manage these complexities yourself. For instance, MyGroup might be better off with the Row being the top level object and eliminate the non-container Item.

One other note that can be confusing about this. By default Item::clip is false. That means you will still be able to see the children of a 0px X 0px Item unless they are covered by another object in the Z direction (as is the case in this question).

Therefore, it sometimes helps to set clip = true when debugging strange layout issues.